# Create a keystore with a CA-signed PrivateKeyEntry

Tags: ssl, openssl, keytool

I would like to refresh a small Java keystore, updating dates to 10 years in the future.
My keystore contains 2 entries, seen with `keytool -v -list` :

```
    Alias name: myCA
    Creation date: Feb 5, 2018
    Entry type: trustedCertEntry
    ...
    Owner: contains all properties needed for myCA ...
    Issuer: same properties as myCA (so self-signed certificate)
    ...
    Alias name: myHost
    Creation date: Feb 5, 2018
    Entry type: PrivateKeyEntry
    Certificate chain length: 2
    Certificate[1]:
    Owner: CN=myhost, etc ...
    Issuer: same properties as myCA
    ...
    Certificate[2]:
    Owner: same properties as myCA
    Issuer: same properties as myCA 
    ...
```

I only achieved to create 2 entries of type trustedCertEntry in my new keystore, I would like to create a trustedCertEntry and a PrivateKeyEntry
What commands can I do to create a myCA-signed private key and add it to the new keystore ?

PS will peers which are today validating myCa sefl-signed certificate validate the new one if I only use the same properties for myCA ? is it enough ?

Answer (score 1):

With patience ....

```
    openssl pkcs12 -export -out temp.p12 -inkey myHost.key -in myHost.crt -certfile myCA.crt
    keytool -v -importkeystore -srckeystore temp.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12 -destkeystore mystore
```